# How can i sort the flatlist by it's price from data in react-native?

Tags: react-native

I want to add sorting button for price high to low and low to high and also for recently added. I can't find proper way to do it.

I'd added button on top bar of the stack screen. And i want to sort the list on main screen.

Below is the data which comes from api(you can use any other dummy):

```
useEffect(() => {
    let tok = authContext.user;
    let id = authContext.userid;
    axios
      .post(
        url.productlist,
        qs.stringify({
          fcm_token: tok,
          sort: 1,
          user_id: id,
          page: 1,
        }),
        {
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
          },
        }
      )
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data);
        setProducts(response.data.products);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log("Something Went Wrong : " + err);
      });
  }, []);
```

Below is the flatlist code(i want to sort by hight to low/ low to high/recently added):

```
<FlatList
              data={products}
              keyExtractor={(item) => item.id.toString()}
              renderItem={({ item }) => (
                <ItemList
                  title={item.name}
                  category={item.category}
                  stock={item.quantity}
                  price={item.price}
                  imageUri={item.image}
                  imageGallery={item.gallery_images}
                  navigation={navigation}
                  description={item.description}
                  yid={item.youtube_video_id}
                />
              )}
            />
```

Comment: Flatlist renders the array of data that you pass into it, so in your case it is products. And it will render the data from index 0 to "last index". You need to sort your array for the flatlist to render the elements in an order that you want it to. I recommend you to take a look at the docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: using sort method `a > b ? 1 : -1` maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code which is working for me:

````
const Asc = () => {
    fullData.sort(function (obj1, obj2) {
      return obj1.price - obj2.price;
    });
    setFullData([...fullData]);
  };

  const Desc = () => {
    fullData.sort(function (obj1, obj2) {
      return obj2.price - obj1.price;
    });
    setFullData([...fullData]);
  };```
````